# DTWCLUST Shape Based Cluster Analysis in R: NA/NaN/Inf in Foreign Function Call Despite Complete Dataset

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

we are currently trying to run a shape based with the dtwclust package and are running in the following problem:
For certain subsets of our data receive this error message:

```
Error in stats::hclust(stats::as.dist(distmat), method, members = dots$members) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 11)
```

At first, we thought we might have missing data in our dataframe. 
However, we tested for NAs, NaNs, Infs and datatype (numeric) and everything turns out okay.

To make it even weirder - it seems to work when subsetting the data into chunks of around 1.5k rows in size. Other variables work just fine.

We cannot find any consistent patterns and do not seem to come closer to a solution - and would greatly appreciate your expertise and help.

To make the error reproducible, please find the code and complete dataset attached.

Code:

```
require(dtwclust)
hc_anger_sbd_k10 <- tsclust(anger, type = "h", k = 10L, preproc = zscore, seed = 100, distance = "sbd", centroid = shape_extraction, control = hierarchical_control(method="average"))
```

Data:
[Dropbox Link To Data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4lgp2xwl4kooogi/20190108_DatasetForReproduction.RData?dl=0)

Thanks so much and kind regards

Comment: I haven't looked at the dataset, but I've heard of other people having problems with SBD for certain unspecified cases. You should try something like `dm <- proxy::dist(zscore(anger), method="sbd")` to get the cross-distance matrix and see if there are NA/NaN/Inf values, and if so, with which pairs of series. Maybe z-normalization itself is the issue, so also look at the series after `zscore(anger)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have empty series, i.e. series whose values are all zero.
For example `anger[1949,]`.
According to the definition of SBD, the distance between such series and any other is infinite.

You'll probably have to remove them with something like `anger[rowSums(anger) != 0,]`.

Comment: Thank you so much! This indeed solves the problem! We never thought of it at first hand!

Comment: Thanks, Alexis! That’s very helpful - I will check that out.